# How do I start a service in a new thread?

Tags: android, android-service

How do I start my service in a new thread. I looked on other questions but it dint work for me. What changes do I need to make in my service when normally running and when running in a separate thread?

Answer (score 8):

Rename your `public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId)` method to `_onStart` and use this new `onStart` implementation:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {
     Thread t = new Thread("MyService(" + startId + ")") {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             _onStart(intent, startId);
             stopSelf();
         }
     };
     t.start();
 }

 private void _onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {
     //Your Start-Code for the service
 }
```

**For API Levels 5 and Above**

`public void onStart(Intent, int)` was deprecated at API level 5. This should be replaced with `public int onStartCommand(Intent, int)`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int startId){
    //All code from 'onStart()' in above placed here as normal.
}

private void _onStart(final Intent intent, final int startId) {
     //Your Start-Code for the service
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MD what do you mean? It clearly provides an answer... Maybe you meant another post?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can start your service in a new thread, but what you can do is start a new thread in your service.

This is because like the activity, the service has life cycle methods that run on the main thread.

So your service will run on the main thread but it will do the heavy lifting on a new thread that it creates when ever it needs to.

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 2):

Citing from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

"Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process. This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive (such as MP3 playback) or blocking (such as networking) operations, it should spawn its own thread in which to do that work. More information on this can be found in Processes and Threads. The IntentService class is available as a standard implementation of Service that has its own thread where it schedules its work to be done."

Comment: I already read that :) Its just that I'm not able to figure out how to get my service running in new thread. I tried with code from other questions in this forum, but dint work for me.

Comment: Did you use IntentService like here? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Alternatively you might create a WorkerThread like this: 
private final class WorkerThread extends Thread {
 public Handler handler;

 @ Override
 public void run() {
     Looper.prepare();
     this.handler = new Handler() {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
  case MSG_DO_MY_JOB:
   // ...
  break;
  case MSG_STOP:
                YourOuterClass.this.stopSelf();
  break;
        }
         }
        };
    Looper.loop();
   }
}
Start the worker when the service is created and send messages to the handler when you want something done.

Answer (score -1):

In my project, i have someone like this and it's work:

```
Thread welcomeThread = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        super.run();
        while (isMyServiceRunning() != true) {
            sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("EXc=" + e);
    } finally {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainPage.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
};

welcomeThread.start();
```

Comment: so, what ? change startActivity to startService(i);

Comment: There was nothing in logcat. Infact I tried running service without the thread, somehow it wasnt working anyways... So I've left it for the moment till Monday... Anyways thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: For me this launch the service from a new thread but service is created and run in the old thread